# ?gclid= is dropped during redirect to https in Magento

Tags: magento

So i have a problem with my redirects in magento. All the incoming traffic from http:// is redirected to https:// for every page. However when http://example.com?gclid=Test123 is redirected, the parameter part is removed/dropped. If I try it using https://example.com?gclid=Test123, it works.

This looks like it has to be configured in my .htaccess but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This proved to be a problem with the FPC cache extension I was using. After stopping all cache tools, everything worked.